# Vertically align an asterisk (*) with a label in an HTML Form

Tags: html, css

On my form, I put an asterisk (*) behind a label to mark it as important.

The problem is that it vertically aligned as top position by default. I am hoping that there's some way through which I can vertically align it as middle.

This is how it looks:
[image]

Notice the * to be top aligned.

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
.imp {
        display: inline-table;
        vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: could you also post the markup?

Comment: Show your HTML markup (by editing the question). Also specify *how* the asterisk should be aligned. What exactly should be aligned to what?

Comment: I'm assuming you are putting the * in its own element? Post html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: sub`.

```css
.verified span{
    vertical-align:sub;
}
```

```html
<p class="verified"><span>*</span> verified</p>
```

Comment: One of those rare occasions when a web dev solution is so beautifully simple.

Answer (score 23):

The `vertical-align: sub` method also expands the container height. 
Since you also tagged `html` for the question, you can use the html entity for native middle asterisk.

```
&lowast;
```

Demo:

Here is the default asterisk **(*)**.
Here is the middle asterisk **(∗)**.

Comment: Or use the low asterisk UNICODE in CSS: `content: '\204e'`

Answer (score 4):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/yce0mbux/1/

```
<span style="line-height:30px;vertical-align:middle" >*</span><label>Some text</label>
```

Answer (score 4):

use `pseudo` element `before`

```css
.imp {
  display: block;
  line-height: 26px;
}
.imp:before {
  content: '*';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="imp">Mandatory</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a nested child element, add one like so:

```
<div>
    <span id="one">
        *
    </span>
     some text
</div>
```

You need to define both `height` and `line-height` to achieve the effect that you want.

```
#one{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 15px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yvaf0s4z/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this method:

```
.your-label {
 display: inline-table;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 15px; /* Adjust as needed to make space for the asterisks */
 /* You need a given dimension to prevent overlap */
      }


.your-label:before {
 position: absolute;
 content: '*';
 left: 0; /* Adjust as needed */
 top: 3px; /* Adjust as needed */
}
```

[See working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/fdvfb1zs/)

**Note:** Inserting as shown above, gives you the independence to position as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `relative` instead of `absolute` to get a better alignment.

```
.required::before {
    position: relative;
    content: '*';
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
   }
```